# Geocoder gem: is there a way to record IP of someone who merely visits the website using geocoder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-geocoder

I have a very low traffic web site and I want to record the IP address of everyone who visits it.

I know Ruby geocoder can detect IP of whoever's making a request

```
request.ip  # =>    "216.232.140.27"
```

However, I'm not sure how I can record this to a database or somehow store it so I can see it if someone just visits my website.

i.e my problem/mental blockage seems to be that I expect someone to click a button in order to trigger a method but I want the IP address stored by someone just visiting....

Can someone explain how I could write a method to store the IP address in a database (or somewhere other than a database such as the logs if that's better) if someone merely visits my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, then you dig in the wrong direction.

First, `ip` method is contained in a standard `request`, it is not relevant to the Geocoder: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-ip

Second, much easier to install third-party statistics in order then keep track of all visitors (by ip or whatever you want). For example: http://www.google.com/analytics/

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah, but google analytics doesn't show you the actual ip address. I need the ip address.

Comment: I'm sorry, did not know that exactly about Google Analytics.
I meant something similar, a third-party service statistics. Really no one that would do the statistics by ip?
The first thing I found: http://www.tracemyip.org/tools/website-visitors-counter-traffic-tracker-statistics/. And you can just google for it: https://www.google.ru/search?q=website%20analytics%20ip%20address%20tracking

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer/wiki/Creating-a-request-database

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'm a bit of a newbie. Can you clarify. If I understand it correctly, I don't even need to store it to the database. Does it work if I just do $ request-log-analyzer log/production.log .  This gem also gets the IP without me needing to use geocoder? I see that it creates a table for IP.

Comment: Yep: this creates a database table that stores a log of all requests, as you don't strictly speaking need the geocoder gem to get the request log. Generally request logs will show the IP address the request came from.